# Can't unmap key mapping to its default permenantly

Tags: key-bindings

I mapped `<C-X>` to `"*d` and now I can't revert it back. I want it to subtract number by 1 like default, but I can't unmap it permanently, it's set to `<C-X>` in every new session. I'm sure .vimrc is not mapping it.

Comment: Try to remove your ```~/.viminfo```. It saves the last session-infos. That resets all session-stuff. But that is not the normal way to go! But it could help for now.

Comment: Use `:verbose nmap {keys}` to look up mappings where where they where last set, e.g. `:verbose nmap "*d`. For more help see `:h :map-verbose`

Answer (score 2):

In general, `:unmap <C-x>` can get rid of he mapping (note the variants like `:nunmap`, etc.).

However, it is strange that the mapping persists without being in your `.vimrc`. You can use `:verbose map <C-x>` to see where the mapping is coming from.